# React Component: updating components, based on another component with no relation

Tags: reactjs, components

I do not know if the title is clear or not, 
here is the issue i am facing at the moment. I have very less exp. of react, would really appreciate the help

I have a list of products based on categories, the categories are defined, A, B and C

I created separate components for all the categories, so Acomponent list all products under A. Bcomponent list all products under B and so on. Separated them because they have different functionalities. They are all being displayed on a single page, and are called by a single parent component

```
render(){
<div>
    <Acomponent />
    <Bcomponent />
    <Ccomponent />
</div>
}
```

I have a select box in front of all the products in the list, from where a user can update the category of the product. So a product in B will have select box with options, A and C.

The problem is that i can update the current product's component, when the product category is updated, which removes it from current category component list, but i need to update the component in which it was moved to.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Would need a more detailed example to help you, could you try to setup something on https://codesandbox.com or https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Consider using context API or state management packages like mobx or redux.

Comment: Redux and global state management is your only option unless you propagate information upwards until you hit a shared parent and set the prop down (but please don't do this).

Comment: @Andrew can you please explain regarding redux ?

Comment: @Emil can you please explain regarding redux ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent component of the three product types.  Write your method to change the product in the parent component, in pseudocode,

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      aProducts: { ... },
      ...
    }
  }

  changeProductType = (product, oldType, newType) => {
    product.type = newType
    this.setState({ 
      [`${oldType}products`]: this.state[`${oldType}products`].filter( p => p !== product.id),
      [`${newType}products`]: [...this.state[`${newType}products`], product
    })

  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Aproducts changeProductType={this.changeProductType} products={this.state.aProducts}/>
      <Bproducts ... />
      <Cproducts ... />
    )
  }
}
```

You pass the `changeProductType` method down to each product in props.  When the product calls it, it takes data from the browser (you'll write something like `onSelect={_ => props.changeProductType(props.name, props.type, newType)}` in the selector in the component's logic).  Then it executes in the scope where it's originally defined (i.e. the top-level component).

There, it redefines the state of its old & new products arrays (the rather unpretty interpolation in `changeProductType` above), removing it from one and adding it to the other.  This change in state will result in a rerender, and the new props will be passed down to both categories.

A cleaner solution is to keep a unified collection of products in state, each with a 'type' attribute, and split them out to your components in the render method.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      products: { ... },
      ...
    }
  }

  changeProductType = (product, newType) => {
    editProduct = this.state.products.find( p => p.id === product.id )
    editProduct.type = newType
    this.setState({ products[id]: editProduct })
  }

  render() {
    let aProducts = this.state.products.filter( p => p.type === 'A' )
    ...
    return(
      <Aproducts changeProductType={this.changeProductType} products={aProducts}/>
      <Bproducts ... />
      <Cproducts ... />
    )
  }
}
```

This is all a bit hand-wavey, so let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: I dont want to get all the items in the parent component. Each component calls an API endpoint to get their respective data

Answer (score 0):

I have been to resolve this, using redux as suggested by @Emil and @Andrew. Please let me know if what i did is correct!

in all the category components, i added the following

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  dispatchedValue: state.dispatchComponent
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  triggerComponent: (compName) => dispatch(triggerComponent(compName))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Acomponent);
```

On select value change i dispatch the component name to be updated, something as following

```
handleSelectChange(value){
    // UPDATE CURRENT LIST
    ...............

    // GETTING COMPONENET NAME USING VALUE
    let component = this.mapComponenet(value)

    // UPDATE OTHER COMPONENET
    this.props.triggerComponent(component);
}
```

and then use `componentDidUpdate` to trigger the API call on the other component

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.props.dispatchedValue == this.state.componentName){
      // UPDATE COMPONENET CODE
    }
}
```

Let me know if there are some issues related to it, or it should not have been used in such a say, the drawback and stuff.